# How to view subject alternate names in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, ssl-certificate

I am setting up a public-facing web site, that has three domain names:

- prod.example.com
- test.example.com
- dev.example.com

I have the TLS certificate, signed by DigiCert, and when I view the site in Firefox, I can click on the URL padlock icon, click the "Connection secured ->" flyout menu, then on "More information", and then in the pop-up "Page Info" window, "Security" tab, I click on the "View Certificate" button, and a new browser tab opens, and shows me all three "Subject Alt Names".

How do I display the same information in Google Chrome?  If my memory serves me correct, that information used to be avilable.